# One off issue parsing SnS json with Python for Lambda

Tags: python

I am writing a LAMBDA function in AWS that is parsing anincomging SNS message in JSON format. I'm no Python expert, but this seems like odd behavior to me. The first line where I try to access the "EC2InstanceId" on `msg`, it fails with:

```
string indices must be integers: TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 16, in lambda_handler snsmessage = msg['EC2InstanceId'] TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The interesting part is that I get this error no matter which `msg` attribute I try to access, even ones that succeed when they are not first! Of the three I am trying to retrieve, the first one always throws this error. Can someone help me understand why the first one throws the error and the other two don't, regardless of which one I make first? Irrelevent account specific info purposely stripped.

**The Python:**

```
import boto3
import json
import os

# Load the SNS message for parsing

print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2) )

records = event['Records'][0]
sns_data = records['Sns']
msg = sns_data['Message']
print msg

snsmessage = msg['EC2InstanceId']
print("From SNS: " + snsmessage )
print msg

#Retrieve the LifeCycle Hook Name
lifecyclehook = msg['LifecycleHookName']
print ("LifeCycleHookName: " + lifecyclehook)
print msg

#Retrieve the Auto Scaling Group Name
AutoScalingGroupName = msg['AutoScalingGroupName']
print ("AutoScalingGroupName: " + AutoScalingGroupName)
```

**The incoming Json:**

```
{ Records": [
          {
          "EventVersion": "1.0",
          "EventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxx:app1-autoscaling-add-to-targetgroup:93cef81b-0379-4ab2-a76f-321c004a8308",
          "EventSource": "aws:sns",
          "Sns": {
            "SignatureVersion": "1",
            "Timestamp": "2018-04-11T23:15:37.616Z",
            "Signature": "YV7sdI+VsTG/X9wA/NgcGhSMtG/3ggZck7ZkRXpKpW4QGilh3f0iGWZjVcOlGoZikcHSyI9v13Zw/zlwTrc2kRBhocE0utzu/DnYd+JOsrRxhlzfyIPf178PlR10zEuaiNKow2M4TKTMy4xxHcL6WqQgiqfVNl0QlWFgi65shmB/6UwSD0frpvaBFXPryrV8ij/Vtt7WQgd6AKq/LdnFJvwJLDrQJ7aHOh0IT6NK/+NemB3RnHeRX1z7CqTCR5BcA//yISgNHExO/NCBGGIbfx5Crk1W6zWxu1NzefXFMQqdRwgbzp7gECOWM/LCzeiJZHKB48L0V+6OMK3cq2TjNw==",
            "SigningCertUrl": "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-433026a4050d206028891664da859041.pem",
            "MessageId": "bb32cb1e-e6b2-5ce3-9e07-98567febcbbf",
            "Message": {
              "LifecycleHookName": "app1-hook",
              "AccountId": "",
              "RequestId": "",
              "LifecycleTransition": "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCHING",
              "AutoScalingGroupName": "xxxxxxxxx",
              "Service": "AWS Auto Scaling",
              "Time": "2018-04-11T23:15:37.573Z",
              "EC2InstanceId": "i-xxxxxxxxxx",
              "LifecycleActionToken": ""
            },
            "MessageAttributes": {},
            "Type": "Notification",
            "UnsubscribeUrl": "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:189825870243:app1-autoscaling-add-to-targetgroup:93cef81b-0379-4ab2-a76f-321c004a8308",
            "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxxxxxxx:app1-autoscaling-add-to-targetgroup",
            "Subject": "Auto Scaling: Lifecycle action 'LAUNCHING' for instance i-xxxxxxxx in progress."
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: When you `print msg` after setting `msg`, what is the output?

Comment: In SNS, you need to parse your `msg` field after parsing the payload. The `Message` field in the SNS payload is a string.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Any idea why it only throws the error on the first one? Is the data somehow modified for the 2nd and third after the first attempt?